# Update Records through Record Triggered Flow without Loop

Tags: salesforce-flow

I want to update records of opportunity> stage name > closed lost when a custom field "out of business" on account object is checked. The flow doesn't run! What could be the process? Please help out!

I specified the condition in start element and then used update records element

[image]

Comment: A change to an `Account` isn't going to cause a flow on `Opportunity` to run. Flows run when there is some change being made to a record. Opportunity not changing = flow is not run. The `AccountId equals recordId` here would also never be satisfied because `recordId` would be for your `Opportunity`. This flow would need to be on `Account`, and you would need to loop over the related `Opportunity` records, there's no way around needing a loop somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include more detail about your flow.  Is it built on the Account object?  Please [edit] your post to include your entry conditions and your debug results.

Comment: @DerekF Record-Triggered Flows don't need to use Get Records + Loop, they can skip straight to the "updating records" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trigger this from the source record that is changing. In this case, you'd add the trigger to the Account object, then use the Update Related Records element to close the opportunities. That might look something like this:

[image: Account record-triggered flow that closes all open opportunities, showing the Start element]

[image: Account record-triggered flow that closes all open opportunities, showing the Update Related Records element]

Comment: it looks like this

Comment: could you please post a picture of start element too? coz its not working

Comment: @rameesha I've updated my answer.

Comment: could you please share the update records element again? Coz I think I might be making a mistake

Comment: @rameesha I redid the screenshots again. They should be more illuminative now.

Comment: thank you so much! it works

Comment: Though I wanted to ask when I was trying to debug the flow and trying to edit out of business field, it won't let me! What could be the issue?

Comment: @rameesha I'm not sure. It could be a field level security issue, or maybe it's not actually a checkbox (e.g. a formula). I'd need to know more about how the field is configured.